# Bullet hole "in" or "through" head

Tags: prepositions

A:   Describe the body, please?

B:   Male. African-American. Tall. With a bullet hole in/through his head.

Should it be "in" or "through" here?

Comment: Please please please don't tell me this is an actual situation that you were in.

Answer (score 1):

That should be "in". If the bullet had gone through, there would have been two holes. On the other hand, the bullet may have made a single hole through the skull.